# How to set web3 provider from external host?

Tags: testrpc, web3-providers

I have installed testrpc in AWS and also started it with `testrpc -h 'my address'`. In remix ide when I choose web3 provider and set url to myaddress:8545 it shows '`Not possible to connect to the Web3 provider. Make sure the provider is running and a connection is open (via IPC or RPC).`' I make sure it is running on AWS. This is purely for demo purpose, also I need some public address along with some ethers. What things should I consider to make sure web3 provider is from my AWS server. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the port 8545 is open on your AWS instance for public connections.

And also include, 
`--rpcaddr "0.0.0.0"` to allow for external connections

Comment: Are we required to have `--rpcaddr "0.0.0.0"` when running `geth`?

Comment: It really depends on what you're doing. For this question, that would seem to be an appropriate thing to do. For development on a VPS, it's something I generally do as well. But in a production environment you'd want to limit it to localhost. Your comment greatly improves the answer so I'll probably include it.